# Gazebo installation with ROS Groovy

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I am a newbee.. I have recently installed ubuntu precise and Ros groovy (full desktop) by following the instructions on the ros wiki. Next I am trying to install the Gazebo. I have done the following commands:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu quantal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'

wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gazebo

. /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh
echo "source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
gazebo

when i run the last command, I get the following error:
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.0.2
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Serial number of failed request:  16
Current serial number in output stream:  17

Please help, as this is an urgent work and i am time bound.
regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2992/gazebo-installation-with-ros-groovy/) by [SAMJT](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/366/samjt/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thank you for the reply... ur clue has really helped out.
On google search, I found the following forum answer and it is working for me now
http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513

cheers :-)

---

Originally posted by [SAMJT](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/366/samjt/) with karma: 16 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-05-25**:
I am glad you made it work, you should mark your answer as correct, in case if others run into the same problem, they know how to fix it. And maybe add to the title something regarding ATI graphics cards, so it will make more sense. Cheers :)